# How come I have Google IPs with the comment `# __CE_WATERMARK__` in my hosts file?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

The `/etc/hosts` file on my MacBook Pro running macOS High Sierra 10.13.6, has the following extra lines at the top of my hosts file. If I remove them they come back.

```
216.239.32.20 www.google.ac # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.ad # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.ae # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.al # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.am # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.as # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.at # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.az # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.ba # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.be # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.bf # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.bg # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.bi # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.bj # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.bs # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.bt # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.by # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.ca # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.cat # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.cc # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.cd # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.cf # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.cg # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.ch # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.ci # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.cl # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.cm # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.cn # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.co.ao # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.co.bw # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.co.ck # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.co.cr # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.co.id # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.co.il # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.co.in # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.co.jp # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.co.ke # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.co.kr # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.co.ls # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.co.ma # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.co.mz # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.co.nz # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.co.th # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.co.tz # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.co.ug # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.co.uk # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.co.uz # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.co.ve # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.co.vi # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.co.za # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.co.zm # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.co.zw # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.com # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.com.af # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.com.ag # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.com.ai # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.com.ar # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.com.au # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.com.bd # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.com.bh # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.com.bn # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.com.bo # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.com.br # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.com.bz # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.com.co # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.com.cu # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.com.cy # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.com.do # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.com.ec # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.com.eg # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.com.et # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.com.fj # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.com.gh # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.com.gi # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.com.gt # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.com.hk # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.com.jm # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.com.kh # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.com.kw # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.com.lb # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.com.lc # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.com.ly # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.com.mm # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.com.mt # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.com.mx # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.com.my # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.com.na # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.com.nf # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.com.ng # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.com.ni # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.com.np # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.com.om # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.com.pa # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.com.pe # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.com.pg # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.com.ph # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.com.pk # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.com.pr # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.com.py # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.com.qa # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.com.sa # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.com.sb # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.com.sg # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.com.sl # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.com.sv # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.com.tj # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.com.tn # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.com.tr # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.com.tw # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.com.ua # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.com.uy # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.com.vc # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.com.vn # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.cv # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.cz # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.de # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.dj # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.dk # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.dm # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.dz # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.ee # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.es # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.fi # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.fm # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.fr # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.ga # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.ge # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.gf # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.gg # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.gl # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.gm # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.gp # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.gr # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.gy # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.hn # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.hr # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.ht # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.hu # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.ie # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.im # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.io # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.iq # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.ir # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.is # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.it # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.je # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.jo # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.kg # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.ki # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.kz # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.la # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.li # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.lk # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.lt # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.lu # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.lv # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.md # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.me # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.mg # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.mk # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.ml # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.mn # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.ms # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.mu # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.mv # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.mw # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.ne # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.nl # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.no # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.nr # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.nu # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.pl # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.pn # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.ps # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.pt # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.ro # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.rs # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.ru # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.rw # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.sc # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.se # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.sh # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.si # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.sk # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.sm # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.sn # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.so # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.st # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.td # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.tg # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.tk # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.tl # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.tm # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.tn # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.to # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.tt # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.us # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.vg # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.vu # __CE_WATERMARK__
216.239.32.20 www.google.ws # __CE_WATERMARK__
```

What is causing the lines to appear and how can I stop this from happening?

Comment: You shouldn't have anything in your hosts file. Apple puts 9 lines - only three entries that are not commented out: "127.0.0.1 localhost & 255.255.255.255 broadcasthost & ::1 localhost" So this really is about whatever software you added to edit that file...

Comment: @bmike, correct. That's why I started looking into it.

Answer (score 5):

I looked at what process was writing to that file after I removed those lines and it looked like it was the Google Chrome Helper processes. After removing all my plugins except the Covenant Eyes plugin it was still writing to that file. I reached out to their support and they could confirm that the software was doing that in order to force Google to use SafeSearch.

Comment: Wow - great work - google chrome messing with that file gives me the serious heebie jeebies - what on earth is it doing to mess with your routing and networking like that?

Comment: @bmike, Covenant Eyes said they do it to force Google to use SafeSearch. I'm not a fan of them messing with the file either, but for what Covenant Eyes does as a software and what their customers want their software to do, it seems reasonable if that's the only way they can do it.